# SQL Server : CASE when any of 10 columns agree

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have 10 columns (items) in one table, 10 in another table.

I want to identify cases where any one of the columns/items in the one table match any one of the columns/items in the other table.

My code below is for three items and is inefficient - how can it be modified for 10 columns/items?

```
CASE
   WHEN (t1.[item1] = t2.[item1] OR t1.[item1] = t2.[item2] OR t1.[item1] = t2.[item3])
     OR (t1.[item2] = t2.[item2] OR t1.[item2] = t2.[item1] OR t1.[item2] = t2.[item3])
     OR (t1.[item3] = t2.[item3] OR t1.[item3] = t2.[item1] OR t1.[item3] = t2.[item2])
     THEN 1
   ELSE 0 
END AS [match]
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: normalize the table so the item fields are their own sub-field, then you only have to match ONE field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is more efficient, but it's simpler to write: Use IN instead of equality test.  e.g.,

```
WHEN t1.item1 IN (T2.item1, T2.item2, T2.item3)
```

For a more efficient way, (but more involved process) use UNPIVOT to convert each column value into a separate row for each table. If the new tables are only used for this process, put a clustered index on the current key-column, as well as the item column. From here, you could do a JOIN to find matching values.

Comment: It's not more efficient; `x IN (y,z)` is equivalent to `x = y OR x = z`. But it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to normalize the table you can use "IN" syntax and generate case condition in program:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.a, tbl1.b, tbl1.c,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tbl1.a IN (tbl2.a,tbl2.b,tbl2.c) OR tbl1.b IN (tbl2.a,tbl2.b,tbl2.c) OR tbl1.c IN (tbl2.a,tbl2.b,tbl2.c) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match
FROM (VALUES (1,1,2,3),(2,2,3,4),(3,3,4,5)) AS tbl1(id,a,b,c),
(VALUES (1,6,7,8),(2,7,8,9),(3,1,5,8)) AS tbl2(id,a,b,c)
GROUP BY tbl1.id,tbl1.a,tbl1.b,tbl1.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to take 2 tables with multiple columns for the item values, unpivot them so the item values are in a single column and then join the 2 new data sets to get only the matches:

```
Select T1.ObjID,T1.ItemValue
From (
        Select objID,ItemValue
        from T1
            unpivot 
            (ItemValue FOR ItemValues IN (I1, I2, I3, I4)) As IVs
    )T1
Inner join 
    (Select objID,ItemValue
        from T2
            unpivot 
            (ItemValue FOR ItemValues IN (I1, I2, I3, I4)) As IVs
    )T2
    on T1.ObjID = T2.ObjID 
        and T1.ItemValue = T2.ItemValue
```

To return just the ID indicating where there is a match, you can just use a `Select Distinct ObjID` instead of the `Select ObjID,ItemValue`

To improve the speed, create actual tables to hold the data and ensure there is an index on the ObjID and ItemValue column. I would make that the clustered key for this table, in which case, when loading the data, make sure the data is sorted. E.g.

```
Insert Into T1_withIndex (ObjID, ItemValue) 
Select objID,ItemValue
    from T1
        unpivot 
        (ItemValue FOR ItemValues IN (I1, I2, I3, I4)) As IVs
    Order by ObjID, ItemValue
```